# tensorflow inception error on Nvidia TX1

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia

I tried to run tensorflow (version:0.9) inception module on Nvidia TX1.

- Step 1
  I run command "bazel build inception/imagenet_train" then I get response:

  `INFO: Found 1 target...
  Target //incpetion:imagenet_train up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train
  INFO: Elapsed time: 0.282s, Critical Path: 0.00s`
- Step 2
  I run bazel-bin/inception/imagnet_train (with argument according README), but I get error:

  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../tensorflow/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_train.py", line 25, in <module>
  from inception import inception_train
  ImportError: No module named inception`

Any help on how to solve this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the version from https://github.com/tensorflow/models? I just cloned that repository, and it seems to do the imports fine (although I don't have the imagenet data so I can't go much further).

Comment: Yes. You can use below steps to download imagenet data.                                   # location of where to place the ImageNet data
DATA_DIR=$HOME/imagenet-data

# build the preprocessing script.
bazel build inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet

# run it
bazel-bin/inception/download_and_preprocess_imagenet "${DATA_DIR}"

Comment: If you `ls -alh bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/inception/`, what do you see? Are the symlinks valid, and is there one for inception_train.py?

Comment: Yes. The inception_train.py has symlink. [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/iWZ5l)

Comment: Seems like it has to be something weird with the python PATH. If you go to `bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/`, open a python prompt, then `import inception`, do you get the same error (this works for me)?

Comment: I go to bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/, and import inception on python prompt that is working. I execute "python imagenet_train.py at bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_train.runfiles/inception/, that responses the same error (ImportError: No module named inception).

Comment: I guess it's worth trying a `bazel clean`. If that doesn't work, what is your operating system and version, bazel version (just run `bazel` and it should say `bazel release X.X.X`), and python version (`python --version`)?

Comment: bazel clean that doesn't work.  Environment: HW: Nvidia TX1 (Jetpack2.3), OS:Ubuntu 16.04, CUDA: 8.0, cuDNN: 5.1, bazel: 0.2.1, python: 2.7.12, tensorflow: r0.9

Comment: Could you try updating to Bazel 0.4.0? That's the only thing that seems like it could cause this which differs from the machine I'm trying to reproduce on.

Comment: The problem is solved. I use Bazel 0.3.2 and tendorflow r0.11..